# Brownian Motion Conditional Probability calculation how to

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I have been recently given a problem on a standard brownian motion and the calculation of the conditional probability, but I am completely lost as where to start.

The problem follows:
Let B(t) be standard Brownian motion. Evaluate: P(B(3)≤3|B(1)=1).

I am sure, this is a basic problem, but I just do not know where to start. I assume the probability would be: the join pdf of B(3)=3 and B(1)=1 divided by pdf of B(1)=1?

Thanks,
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brownian motion is a martingale. So conditioning $B(1)=1$ is equivalent to assuming that you are starting a new Brownian motion, with initial value 1. So $P(B(3)\leq 3|B(1)=1)=P(B(2)\leq 2)$. Can you finish it from here?

Comment: Hi Alex, Thank you! I think, I can: Since brownian motion is normally distributed, P(B(2)<2) = normalcdf(mean = 0, std. = sqrt(2)). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct